# Python: initialize several names simultaneously without giving them the same id

Tags: python

This is what I've tried so far:

```
a, b, c = ([],)*3
a.append(0)
b.append(1)
c.append(2)
print(a,b,c)
>> [0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2]  # Result
>> [0] [1] [2]  # Expected results
```

Comment: `a,b,c = [], [], []` or `a,b,c = ([] for _ in range(3))`

Comment: This is the exact same behaviour as using list multiplication to initialize 2d lists and has the exact same solution: use comprehension or write out the lists manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a, b, c = [],[],[]
>>> id(a),id(b),id(c)
(573212632, 635724224, 626682216)
```

or

```
    >>> a,b,c = ([] for _ in range(3) )
    >>> id(a),id(b),id(c)
    (633263648, 197690032, 633261352)
    >>> a.append(1)
    >>> b.append(2)
    >>> c.append(3)
    >>> a,b,c
    ([1], [2], [3])
```

Comment: `a,b,c = ([] for _ in range(3) )` was what I was looking for! thanks

Comment: @mat  not a problem

Comment: I'm genuinely curious what the advantage the range version is, other than mild obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating only one list and then duplicating it.

So your code is the same as:

```
def build_lists():
    l = []
    return l, l, l
a, b, c = build_lists()
```

So the following would work as that would be creating new lists for each iteration:

`a, b, c = [[] for i in range(3)]`